# How does Nietzsche's understanding of "power" differ from his predecessors?

Tags: nietzsche

> What is good? Everything that heightens the feeling of power in man,
> the will to power, power itself.

Instead of asking what is good, I found myself asking myself what 'power' is. How does Nietzsche's understanding of "power" differ from his predecessors? Could any difference there be what sets Nietzsche apart from his so called "herd"? Did he believe he had completely worked out what it was, so that everyone else can only interpret (or misinterpret) him?

Comment: Nietzsche's will to power can be partly understood through his intellectual dialogue with Spinoza's ideas about "conatus", see https://karolinum.cz/data/clanek/1205/Interpret_2_2013_05_Wiesmann.pdf (in particular the section starting on p. 55 about what Spinoza meant by the idea). I get the impression that Spinoza's conatus was partly motivated by his monism--A.C. Grayling's *History of Philosophy* says that Spinoza wanted to answer questions like "how can human beings be different from each other if they are really all part of the one thing that exists?"

Comment: Nietzsche is merely describing his broken self (who craves power), and not others. It is futile to try to learn anything from a broken personality, except *not* to go down the same useless path.

Answer (score 1):

In [Off the Beaten Track](https://archive.org/stream/ApolloHumanRightsBooks/26585615-Heidegger-Martin-Off-the-Beaten-Track_djvu.txt) (*Holzwege*) Heidegger describes Nietzsche's understanding of power.  It is shown to be inseparable from the will to power.

pages 174 - 175

> It is in the second part of *Thus Spoke Zarathustra* (written during
> 1883,  the year after *La Gaya Scienza* was published) that Nietzsche
> first places the  "will to power" in the context in which it must be
> understood: "Where I  found the living, there I found the will to
> power; and even in the will of the  one who serves I found the will to
> be master."
>
> To will is to will to be master. Will thus understood is found even in
> the  will of him who serves. Not, it is true, in the sense that a
> servant might strive  to emerge from the role of vassal to become a
> master himself. Rather, the  vassal as vassal, the servant as servant,
> always has the will to have something  else under him, over which he
> has command in the course of his service and  whose service he makes
> use of. Therefore, as a vassal he is still a master.  Even to be a
> vassal is to want to be master. ...
>
> To command, which is to be carefully distinguished from merely
> ordering others about, is to overcome oneself and is more difficult
> than  obeying. Will is gathering oneself together for the task at
> hand. Only he who  cannot obey himself must continue to be
> specifically subject to command.  Will strives for what it wills not
> just as for something that it does not yet  have. Will already has
> what it wills. For will wills its willing. Its will is  what it has
> willed. Will wills itself. It exceeds itself. In this way will as will
> wills above and beyond itself, and therefore at the same time it must
> bring  itself beneath and behind itself. This is why Nietzsche can say
> (*The Will to  Power*, no. 675, from 1887/8): "*To will* at all
> amounts to the will to become
> *stronger*, the will to grow. . . "

176

> In the expression "Will to Power" the word "power" gives the essence
> of the mode in which will wills itself to the extent that it is
> command. As  command, will joins itself to itself, i.e., to what it
> has willed. This  self-gathering is the empowering of power. Will
> exists for itself no more than  power for itself. Will and power,
> therefore, are not subsequently linked by  the will to power; rather,
> will, as the will to will, exists as the will to power  in the sense
> of the empowerment of power. Power, however, has its essence  in the
> fact that it stands in relation to will as the will that is inside the
> will.  The will to power is the essence of power. It indicates the
> absolute essence  of will which wills itself as sheer will.
>
> Hence the will to power cannot be dropped in favor of a will to
> something  else, e.g., the "will to nothing"; for this will too is
> still the will to will - that  is what enables Nietzsche to say (*On
> the Genealogy of Morals*, Third Treatise,  § 1, from 1887): "it [the
> will] will will *nothing* rather than *not* will."
>
> To "will nothing" in no way means to will the sheer absence of all
> reality,  but rather precisely to will reality but to will it as a
> nullity everywhere and at  every time and only in this way to will
> annihilation. In such willing, power  is still securing for itself the
> possibility of command and the ability to be  master.
>
> As the essence of will, the essence of the will to power is the
> fundamental  trait of all reality. Nietzsche writes (*The Will to
> Power*, no. 693, from 1888):  The will to power is "the inmost essence
> of being." Here "being" is used  in accordance with the language of
> metaphysics: beings in general. As the  fundamental character of
> beings, therefore, the essence of the will to power  and the will to
> power itself are not to be ascertained through psychological
> observation; rather, it is the other way round: psychology itself gets
> its  essence, i.e., the ability to set and to recognize its object,
> only through the  will to power.

Answer (score 0):

Power before Nietzsche was an aspect of the One, for example, in both Islamic and Christian philosophy and hence orientated to the Good. It's also part of Plato's philosophy and before him, Pythagoras.

With Nietzsche it is detached from that, as he denies the One - part of his infamous 'death of God' rhetoric. With that eliminated as well as the notion of the Good, as part of his 'beyond Good and Evil', power simply becomes capricious and this is why Orff in his opus, the Carmina Burana, and which was influenced by Nietzsche speaks of capricious fortune.

I'd say that capricious power is simply tyrannical power. And Nietzsche bows down before that. This would be simply diabolical in the old way of thinking - as well as today, if only people would draw out the full implications of what he had to say. In fact, Ronald Beiner, a philosopher who was infatuated with Nietzsche in his youth, in his book, *Dangerous Minds*, says exactly that and with one eye on today's political climate.

Answer (score 0):

Nietzsche's usage of power stems from modern philosophy's usage of it. Think Hobbes, Machiavelli, Bacon. Once reason is denied its telos, it becomes a handmaid to the passions, and so the issue is how to best satisfy your passions. Thus power is important, as there is no end for man as such. Read Leo Strauss and Allan Bloom.